# How can I perform a JQuery script when a div element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I am pretty new in JavaScript and JQuery and I have the following problem.

Into a page I have this pretty horrible HTML structure:

```
<a title="WIFI" href="javascript: void(0)" id="showWifi_${item.index}" class="showWifi">
    <div id="wifiIcon_${item.index}"  class="news_box news_box_01 hvr-underline-from-center highLightButton" style="margin-right: 50px; border-radius: 25px;">    </div>
</a>
```

and the inner div have setted a background immage by CSS (this is pretty horrible because I have a div element inside a link...)

By the way, when the user click on the previous link, it is performed this JQuery script defined into the same page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showWifi").click(function(event){

        // Retrieve the id of the clicked element:
        clickedButton = this.id;    
        .............................................
        .............................................
        DO SOMETHING
        .............................................
        .............................................
    });
});
```

Ok, so I have restructured the previous HTML structure in this way:

```
<div id="showWifi" style="float: left; margin-right: 40px;">
    <img src="<c:url value="resources/img/icons/projects/wifi.png" />">
</div>
```

So I have a div that contain an immage.

What I want to do is perform the previous JQuery script when the new div (having **id="showWifi"**) is clicked but actually the previous script can't work on this element because this div element seems to be not clickable.

How can I solve this issue and perform my script when the div having **id="showWifi"** is clicked?

Comment: You need to add CSS class `"showWifi"` as you are using class selector or use `$(".showWifi, #showWifi").click(......)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can use multiple selector here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showWifi,#showWifi").click(function(event){

        // Retrieve the id of the clicked element:
        clickedButton = this.id;    
        .............................................
        .............................................
        DO SOMETHING
        .............................................
        .............................................
    });
});
```

Hope it will Help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div id="showWifi" style="float: left; margin-right: 40px;">
    <img src='<c:url value="resources/img/icons/projects/wifi.png" />'>
</div>
```

then change the selector to id selector instead:

```
$("#showWifi")
```